# Need to switch debian FS readonly writable layer from tmpfs to aufs to not lose files after booting

Tags: debian, filesystems, embedded, tmpfs, aufs

I'm trying to have this done on a debian 9 based embedded system. The fs that come for root is mounted as such in /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
/dev/mmcblk1p1  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
debugfs  /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs  defaults  0  0
```

My current file system looks like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            215M     0  215M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  6.0M   43M  13% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.5G  1.9G  1.4G  59% /
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Now what I'm required to do is use unionfs (or aufs) + ext4 to create a more resilient mounting system because /ext4 might fail due to power outage and file corruption might occur. The idea here is to have a readonly file layer at the bottom with a writable one on top for /home/debian as well as any other that might require system writing to them (like var/log dir). What I was told is that ext4 working with an embedded system that might loss power unexpectedly on regular basis, would cause series disk issues/corruption especially since we are going to be writing to disk alot while our Application is running.[(Link)](https://serverfault.com/questions/391302/can-ext4-fs-be-completely-unrecoverable-broken-due-to-power-loss-while-disk-is-w). IS this completely true even with the presence of Journaling in ext4?

After hours and hours of researching I found that it is suggested to go through the /usr/share/initramfs-tools by creating hooks/scripts and such. After creating new script and booting my system I was able to get something similar to what I had wanted:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            215M     0  215M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  6.0M   43M  13% /run
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.5G  1.9G  1.4G  59% /ro
root.rw         242M  8.5M  234M   4% /rw
root.union      242M  8.5M  234M   4% /
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000
```

&& using mount I get the following details for newly added ro && rw file systems:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p1  on  /ro                              type  ext4        (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
root.rw         on  /rw                              type  tmpfs       (rw,relatime)
root.union      on  /                                type  aufs        (rw,relatime,si=587d3414)
```

Now this has worked in terms of making my initial / read only system that is in /ro dir && I have installed on top a writable layer in /rw. The issue here is that if I create new files/dir they are all gone after booting the device. Looking deep into this I suspect the fact that I was using tmpfs might have caused that since it is used normally for RAM, but I have tough using aufs on top (root.union) would solce tis issue but it didnt.

How can I solve this issue by making the /rw layer retain any new information/files created even after boot? Keep in mind my system is read only now so everytime I try to go into my script and mount /rw as aufs it is reverted back after booting the device.

Note:
Does my current set up mean that logs from my current App are not logged to my /var/log/... and are lost after booting device? some Apps would usually log to /var/log/syslog which is in /rw directory but I can't seem to confirm if they are retaining new logs after boot up or just reverting to what they had at start up in them?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ext4's journalling means that actual corruption is rare, and can be fixed with a fsck. I have never encountered an ext4 corruption in anything but a dying disk (literally refused to spin up the next day).

Linux's caching means that the RAM acts as a tmpfs with a backing store. If you find this too slow (which would be surprising, given that you are using a flash disk), you can increase the time taken to flush the data by adding `commit=<time>` to your fstab, which trades data loss with speed.

Going through trying to find what needs to be written to by programs is a unsolved problem in computer science, above the halting problem in complexity. Why not just store the things you need to persist on a separate partition/disk, so that you can migrate in the case of failure?

Comment: The only other alternative here is SD card and I found that those can be unreliable at time.

Comment: @JJAdams you only need them to not fail at the same time, rather than to be completely reliable.

Comment: @JJAdams the mad part of my brain is suggesting RAID 1 as an option. Raid 1 with flash improves read performance, but not write. If your worried about disk failure, there is not much better than a mirror (except, perhaps, 2 mirrors)